# Google analytics API how to set user's location

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using google Analytics API in extended way. My page manages alot of events what user does.

Since I exactly can tell where user is from (Locally targeted advertisment) I would like to set user's exact location, so it appears in analytics.

Is that possible?

For example it would look like:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'page': '/pagename',
    'location': 'City/district name'
});
```

That way, I could tell how many clients from which place are currently on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics out the box will detect the IP of the user and detect the region/country/city.

But if you want to check that with the data you capture, I would put it in an event and/or custom dimension. e.g.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'user', 'geolocation', '{{yourLocationVar}}');
```

[Event tracking info here.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

[Custom dimensions details here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets), needs a bit more setup but nicer reports

Comment: I tried to setup dimension1 that was set. It wasn't recorded.